# Is there an PHPDoc type hint for an boolean parameter?

Tags: php, phpdoc

I wasn't able to find an overview of the types which can be hinted with PHPDoc. I know array or string, but is there also bool? Like:

```
/**
 * @param bool loadLazy
 * @return array Array with objects
 */
public function getObjects($loadLazy=false) {
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As a "type hint" is only a "hint", I would say you can use pretty much whatever you like.

Still, I tend to use the types that are found in the official PHP manual -- which means, for a [Boolean](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php), I would use `boolean`.

Comment: great answer. vote limit reached today, can't vote up anymore. I'll do that a.s.a.p.

Comment: This answer is misleading. phpDocumentor only supports valid PHP types, class names, and `mixed`.

Answer (score 7):

[According to the documentation](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLframesConverter/default/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.param.pkg.html), you can use any valid [PHP type](http://www.php.net/types), class names, or `mixed`. You can also list multiple types by separating them with a `|` (e.g., `@param int|bool $var`)

Comment: actually, you can't type hint with int or string (http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php)

Comment: Yes you can. We're discussing PHPDoc type hints, not native PHP type hints.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, bool works.

Answer (score 0):

bool is supported in phpDocumentor and phpXref.

C.